# oracle insert only time

Tags: oracle, time, to-date

I would like to insert data to db as time, not date. If I use `to_date('2012-08-31 07:39:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` it adds date too.
If I use `to_date('09:34:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')` it adds year, month, day as well, from nowhere :|
Later I need to get rows where time is between x and y, not taking in account the year, month or day. How do I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DATE` type always includes the date component.

One option is to continue using `DATE` and write your code to ignore the date component.  In order to make queries on the time efficient, you might want to create a function-based index on something like `TO_CHAR( date_field, 'HH24:MI:SS' )` and use that expression in your queries.

Alternatively, you could use a `NUMBER` field to store the number of seconds since midnight, and write your queries in terms of that.

Comment: thanks. so can give me example how querie should look like? select * from table1 where collumn_date between TO_CHAR(collumn_date, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) '08:00:00' and '17:00:00' ?

Comment: `select * from table1 where TO_CHAR(collumn_date, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) between '08:00:00' and '17:00:00'`

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the `date` solution Dave shows, you could use an [`interval`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref167) data type for the column:

```
create table t42(id number, t interval day to second);

insert into t42 (id, t) values(123, to_dsinterval('0 07:39:33'));
insert into t42 (id, t) values(456, to_dsinterval('0 09:34:00'));

select id
from t42
where t between to_dsinterval('0 07:00:00') and to_dsinterval('0 07:59:59');

    ID
----------
       123
```

Displaying intervals is a little awkward as they [don't have format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#BABBICGH), but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/970249/266304) for some ideas if needed. If you only use them for filtering then that may not be an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use number column type and insert value as

```
INSERT INTO table_name (nTime) 
   VALUES (date - trunc(date));
```

and then select values

```
select * 
  from table_name t
 where t.nTime between (10 / 24 + 15 / 24 / 60) and (12 / 24 + 30 / 24 / 60) --between 10:15 and 12:30
```