# Oracle: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following fields:

Reports (table name)
Rep_Date (date)
Rep_Time (date)

The Rep_Time field has values like '01/01/1753 07:30:00' i.e. the time part is relevant.  I have written the following query:

```
select Reports.pid, MaxDate from Reports
INNER JOIN (
    select pid, max(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(REP_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        || TO_CHAR(REP_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) As MaxDate
    from reports
    group by pid
) ReportMaxDate
on Reports.PID = ReportMaxDate.PID
AND To_Date(To_Char(MaxDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) = REP_DATE
WHERE REPORTS.PID=61
```

The derived table part of the query runs, but when I run the entire query I get an error: "not a valid month".  Why is this?

In order to help debug this; if I run the following query:

```
select rep_date, rep_time from reports where pid=61 and rownum=1
```

I get:

```
Rep_Date = 01/04/2009
Rep_Time = 01/01/1753 13:00:00
```

UPDATE 15:58
I am now able to execute the following query:

```
select Reports.pid, MaxDate from Reports
INNER JOIN (
    select pid, max(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(REP_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        || TO_CHAR(REP_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) As MaxDate
    from reports group by pid
) ReportMaxDate
on Reports.PID = ReportMaxDate.PID
AND to_date(to_char(maxdate,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') = REP_DATE
WHERE REPORTS.PID=61
```

However, I need to add one more statement to the `WHERE` clause comparing the time part of MaxDate to rep_time: `to_date(to_char(maxdate,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') = REP_DATE` does not work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1.

```
To_Date(To_Char(MaxDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) = REP_DATE
```

is causing the issue. when you use to_date without the time format, oracle will use the current sessions NLS format to convert, which in your case might not be "DD/MM/YYYY". Check this...

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
26-SEP-12

Which means my session's setting is DD-Mon-YY

SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SY
----------
09/26/2012


SQL> select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY')) from dual;
select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY')) from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month

SQL> select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE(T
---------
26-SEP-12
```

2.

More importantly, Why are you converting to char and then to date, instead of directly comparing

```
MaxDate = REP_DATE
```

If you want to ignore the time component in MaxDate before comparision, you should use..

```
trunc(MaxDate ) = rep_date
```

instead.

==Update : based on updated question.

```
Rep_Date = 01/04/2009 Rep_Time = 01/01/1753 13:00:00
```

I think the problem is more complex. if rep_time is intended to be only time, then you cannot store it in the database as a date. It would have to be a string or date to time interval or numerically as seconds (thanks to Alex, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215281/oracle-insert-only-time/12216981#12216981)) . If possible, I would suggest using one column rep_date that has both the date and time and compare it to the max date column directly.

If it is a running system and you have no control over repdate, you could try this.

```
trunc(rep_date) = trunc(maxdate) and 
to_char(rep_date,'HH24:MI:SS') = to_char(maxdate,'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Either way, the time is being stored incorrectly (as you can tell from the year 1753) and there could be other issues going forward.

Comment: In answer to your question MaxDate is a DateTime and REP_DATE is a Date.  What does trunc(MaxDate ) = rep_date DO?

Comment: trunc(date) would remove the time component (actually, it makes the time component zero, which is the case with a date column such as REP_DATE. There is no such thing as just date in Oracle.)

Comment: +1, thanks it works.  Could you explain how to get the time component of a datetime before I accept? to_date(to_char(maxdate,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') does not seem to work.

Comment: The to_char part is working in your query.The problem is you are trying to convert just the time (10:55:30 for example) into a date. As If you just want to store time, you'll have to do it in a string (varchar2) data type.

Comment: Please see the revision to my question.

Comment: @RajeshChamarthi - just to be pedantic, a time on its own doesn't *have* to be a string, it could be stored numerically as seconds, or [as an interval](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216981/266304), or a time on a fixed date (which the OP already seems to be doing; using 1753 is curious, but then so is using separate date and time fields in the first place). All have conversion implications though.

Answer (score 3):

To know the actual date format, insert a record by using sysdate. That way you can find the actual date format. for example

```
insert into emp values(7936, 'Mac', 'clerk', 7782, sysdate, 1300, 300, 10);
```

now, select the inserted record.

```
select ename, hiredate from emp where ename='Mac';
```

the result is

```
ENAME   HIREDATE
Mac     06-JAN-13
```

voila, now your actual date format is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the value of this database parameter for your session by using the ALTER SESSION command and use it as you wanted

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
SELECT TO_DATE('05-12-2015') FROM dual;

05/12/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize as you wish the format inside the ''

> SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name, 'MONTH-DAY-yy') FROM table_name;