# Formatted SysDate in default value

Tags: oracle, database-design, time

in Oracle, (with pl-sql developer) How can I use a formatted default value in a column? (like this: to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MM:SS') )

I want create this coumns >>

name: f1

type: date

default: to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MM:SS')

Comment: A DATE column does not have a "format"

Answer (score 4):

Oracle doesn't have TIME only columns.  Even if you set a column or variable to just HH24:MI:SS it will still have a date element.

The problem with just storing a time is that it is rarely useful without a date to go with it.   So why not just store the datetime in a single column?

But if you really, really, really want just the time store the "seconds after midnight" as a number:

```
f1 number(5,0) default to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'sssss'))
```

Comment: You *could* also use [an interval](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216981/266304) rather than a number, e.g. `f1 interval day to second(0) default systimestamp - trunc(systimestamp)`, which might be slightly clearer to read, but harder to work with... but also only if you really, really, really want the time on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Date type value does not depend on formatting.
Only when converting date to string, formatting is involved.
You can create formatted column of string values:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  f1 varchar2(20) default to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db0f6/1)