# Is it possible to have 2 formats of Dates inside 1 column?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I would like to know if it is possible to have 2 formats of dates inside one column.

The problem is that I need to have a default value if the table is NULL which is a date, and if the table is NOT null then i would need just a timestamp.

I've made a CASE that should do this, but it won't work.

```
CASE WHEN s.time IS null 
THEN 
  TO_DATE('01-JAN-1901 01:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
ELSE
  TO_DATE(s.time, 'HH24:MI:SS') 
END AS time
```

That statement gives me "*ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.*"

If i try something like this:

```
CASE WHEN s.time IS null 
THEN 
  TO_DATE('01-JAN-1901 01:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
ELSE 
  TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.time, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') 
END AS time
```

It will work, however it will add a date in front of the time - and it will look like this:
(i don't know where it is getting that date from 01-JUL-2013)

```
 TIME
-------
01-JAN-1901 01:00:00
01-JUL-2013 15:35:00
```

instead of this:

```
 TIME
-------
01-JAN-1901 01:00:00
15:35:00
```

(this is what i want)

Comment: You can't have a date column that only holds a time. You're getting `01-JUL-2013` because [as the docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062): "If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month".

Comment: Argh i see, thanks Alex. So there is no way to show only the time in a Date type column - if i understood correctly?

Comment: You can't store only the time; you can show whatever you want when you query. If you only wanted to store a time you could look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12215281/266304), but I'm unclear why you're storing an arbitrary date when the value is null - why not just store null rather than a magic date? Are you really not talking about storing at all, this is only about display values that are already stored?

Comment: Yeah this is about displaying the data that is stored.
So, if the data is null then i should display a date, however if there is already a date i would only like to show a time.
My question is, is possible to do in only 1 column?

Comment: Do you need to work with this values in other query/procedure, or you nedd just an output? Because, if you need just an output, you can just convert all values to char however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's for display only, you need to use `TO_CHAR()` instead of `TO_DATE()` in your `ELSE`, but both branches have to produce a string:

```
CASE WHEN s.time IS null 
THEN 
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-1901 01:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')) 
ELSE
  TO_CHAR(s.time, 'HH24:MI:SS') 
END AS time
```

The `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE())` is redundant unless you want to rely on your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, so this is simpler:

```
CASE WHEN s.time IS null 
THEN 
  '01-JAN-1901 01:00:00'
ELSE
  TO_CHAR(s.time, 'HH24:MI:SS') 
END AS time
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51454/2) of both approaches.

---

You get the ORA-01858 from your initial version because you're passing a `DATE` into `TO_DATE()`. That expects a string argument and this is causing an implicit conversion, so you're really doing:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.time), 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

which based on what your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`setting seems to be is:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(s.time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

so you'd end up trying to do something like:

```
TO_DATE('16-JUL-2013 15:35:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

and you get the error because it's then trying to interpret `JUL` (or whatever month your real data has) as a numeric value for the minutes value, for the `MI` part of the format mask you supplied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. 
This helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring and remove the date

> CASE WHEN s.time IS null 
>   THEN 
>       
> TO_DATE('01-JAN-1901 01:00:00', 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
>   
> ELSE 
>   SUBSTRING()
>   END AS time