# How to have a table column with only minutes and seconds

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database project that I have to insert some music information in it. In one of my tables, I have a column in which I have to insert the track time of all the songs. For that, I was wondering if there is any function (similar to `to_date()`) that I can use in order to insert minute:second format only.

I tried to use `to_timestamp()`. However, it will always give me actual date with the first day of the month that I insert the data.

for example:

```
to_timestamp('9:10','MI:SS')
```

Result:

```
18-06-01, 00:9:10,0000000
```

PS: for the track time column, is it ok to defined the datatype as TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Use `INTEGER` type and store total seconds of the track. You can always convert total seconds to "minute:seconds" format when displaying data.

Comment: However I really need the mm:ss format is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Using a nominal date and only ever extracting the time part isn't a terrible solution (you can use a date column rather than a timestamp if you are not interested in fractional seconds). [An interval might be suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12216981/266304) but they need a bit of work to format. Storing the number of seconds sounds simplest for what you doing. Depends what you need to do with the stored value later, perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support a separate `time` data type.

I would suggest that you store the value as a number of seconds if you want to do arithmetic (such as adding up the values).  If you just want to look at them, use a string format.

If you want to convert a number of seconds to minutes/seconds, you can use:

```
select floor(secs / 60) || ':' || lpad(mod(secs, 60), 2, '0')
```