# Time difference in oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp

Hi i have the following table which contains Start time,end time, total time

---

```
STARTTIME            | ENDTIME             | TOTAL TIME TAKEN  |
02-12-2013 01:24:00  | 02-12-2013 04:17:00 |  02:53:00         |
```

---

I need to update the `TOTAL TIME TAKEN` field as above using the update query in oracle

For that I have tried the following select query

```
select  round((endtime-starttime) * 60 * 24,2),
        endtime,
        starttime 
  from purge_archive_status_log
```

but I'm getting **02.53** as a result, but my expectation format is **02:53:00** Please let me know how can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this post can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970249/format-interval-with-to-char as if `endtime` and `starttime` are of type DATE then `endtime-starttime` will be an interval. BTW why do you want to hold a column with data that can be calculated in the query? not better use [virtual columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#BABIDDJJ)

Comment: @A.B.Cade i have tried like this no use  `select TO_CHAR(NVL(endtime-starttime, TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:00:00'))) from purge_archive_status_log `

Comment: No, according to the post you need to do something like this: `to_char(extract(HOUR FROM (endtime-starttime)), 'fm00') || ':' || to_char(extract(MINUTE FROM (endtime-starttime)), 'fm00') || ':' || to_char(extract(SECOND FROM (endtime-starttime)), 'fm00')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably no reason to have that `total_time_taken` column in your table at all, you can always calculate it's value. But If you insist on keeping it, it would be better to recreated it as column of `interval day to second` data type, not `varchar2`(assuming that that's its current data type). So here are two queries for you to choose from, one returns value of `interval day to second` data type and another one value of `varchar2` data type:

This query returns difference between two dates as a value of `interval day to second` data type:

```
SQL> with t1(starttime, endtime, total_time_taken ) as(
  2    select to_date('02-12-2013 01:24:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  3         , to_date('02-12-2013 04:17:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  4         , '02:53:00'
  5     from dual
  6  )
  7  select starttime
  8       , endtime
  9       , (endtime - starttime) day(0) to second(0) as total_time_taken
 10   from t1
 11  ;
```

Result:

```
STARTTIME            ENDTIME               TOTAL_TIME_TAKEN  
-----------          -----------          ---------------- 
02-12-2013 01:24:00  02-12-2013 04:17:00   +0 02:53:00
```

This query returns difference between two dates as a value of `varchar2` data type:

```
SQL> with t1(starttime, endtime, total_time_taken ) as(
  2    select to_date('02-12-2013 01:24:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  3         , to_date('02-12-2013 04:17:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  4         , '02:53:00'
  5     from dual
  6  )
  7  select starttime
  8       , endtime
  9       , to_char(extract(hour   from res), 'fm00')  || ':' ||
 10         to_char(extract(minute from res), 'fm00')  || ':' ||
 11         to_char(extract(second from res), 'fm00') as total_time_taken
 12    from(select starttime
 13              , endtime
 14              , total_time_taken
 15              , (endtime - starttime) day(0) to second(0) as res
 16          from t1
 17        )
 18  ;
```

Result:

```
STARTTIME            ENDTIME              TOTAL_TIME_TAKEN  
-----------          -----------          ---------------- 
02-12-2013 01:24:00  02-12-2013 04:17:00   02:53:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this too,

```
WITH TIME AS (
SELECT to_date('02-12-2013 01:24:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') starttime, 
       to_date('02-12-2013 04:17:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') endTime
FROM dual)
SELECT to_char(TRUNC ((endTime - startTime)* 86400 / (60 * 60)), 'fm09')||':'||
       to_char(TRUNC (MOD ((endTime - startTime)* 86400, (60*60)) / 60), 'fm09')||':'||
       to_char(MOD((endTime - startTime)* 86400, 60), 'fm09') time_diff
FROM   TIME;
```