# difference between timestamp in oracle in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below records in call_event table;

```
EVENT_ID   TIMESTAMP             EVENT   
---------  -------------------   ------
9000       03/27/2017 18.00.39   Call Start
9000       03/27/2017 18.08.44   Call END
9001       03/28/2017 14.30.27   Call Start
9001       03/28/2017 15.02.56   Call END
```

What query should I write in oracle to get the below result

```
EVENT_ID   TIMESTAMP             EVENT      Call Duration
---------  -------------------   ------     -------------   
9000       03/27/2017 18:00:39   Call Start  00:09:23
9000       03/27/2017 18:08:44   Call END    00:09:23
9001       03/28/2017 14.30.27   Call Start  00:33:29
9001       03/28/2017 15.02.56   Call END    00:33:29
```

Comment: Your call durations seem not to match the timestamp differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE call_event ( EVENT_ID, "TIMESTAMP", EVENT ) AS
SELECT 9000, TIMESTAMP '2017-03-27 18:00:39', 'Call Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9000, TIMESTAMP '2017-03/27 18:08:44', 'Call END' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001, TIMESTAMP '2017-03-28 14:30:27', 'Call Start' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9001, TIMESTAMP '2017-03-28 15:02:56', 'Call END' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       MAX( "TIMESTAMP" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EVENT_ID )
         - MIN( "TIMESTAMP" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EVENT_ID )
         AS "Call Duration"
FROM   call_event;
```

**Output**:

```
EVENT_ID TIMESTAMP           EVENT      Call Duration
-------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
    9000 2017-03-27 18:00:39 Call Start +00 00:08:05.000000
    9000 2017-03-27 18:08:44 Call END   +00 00:08:05.000000
    9001 2017-03-28 14:30:27 Call Start +00 00:32:29.000000
    9001 2017-03-28 15:02:56 Call Start +00 00:32:29.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want two rows for a single call?  I would be inclined to pivot the data:

```
select event_id, min(timestamp) as call_start_ts, max(timestamp) as call_end_ts,
       max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) as duration
from t
group by event_id;
```

If the `timestamp` column is indeed a timestamp, then `duration` will be an `interval`.  The above assumes that calls start before they end.

Having said that, you can do the same thing with window functions if you want separate rows::

```
select event_id, min(timestamp) as call_start_ts, max(timestamp) as call_end_ts,
       (max(timestamp) over (partition by event_id) -
        min(timestamp) over (partition by event_id)
       ) as duration
from t
group by event_id;
```

Comment: I think some phone logging software does that sort of thing. They probably find it easier to add a record that to update one.

Comment: @Manngo . . . I meant in the result set, not in the source data.  It makes lots of sense in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you

```
SELECT A.EVENT_ID, A.TIMESTAMP, A.EVENT, B.TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP_END, B.EVENT AS EVENT_END, B.TIMESTAMP - A.TIMESTAMP AS DURATION
FROM CALL_EVENT A 
INNER JOIN  CALL_EVENT B ON A.EVENT_ID = B.EVENT_ID 
WHERE A.EVENT = 'Call Start'
AND B.EVENT = 'Call END'
```

Answer (score 0):

The trickiest part is the formatting of the datetime intervals involves as there is no shrink-wrapped function in oracle akin to the `TO_CHAR(...)` family:

```
SELECT event_id
     ,           to_char(extract(HOUR   FROM delta), 'fm00')
       || ':' || to_char(extract(MINUTE FROM delta), 'fm00')
       || ':' || to_char(extract(SECOND FROM delta), 'fm00') duration
  FROM (
            SELECT event_id
                 , max(ts) - min(ts) delta
              FROM events
          GROUP BY event_id
       )
     ;
```

A variant handles timestamps that are modelled as `DATE` columns:

```
SELECT event_id
     ,           to_char(extract(HOUR   FROM delta), 'fm00')
       || ':' || to_char(extract(MINUTE FROM delta), 'fm00')
       || ':' || to_char(extract(SECOND FROM delta), 'fm00') duration
  FROM (
            SELECT event_id
                 , numtodsinterval ( max(ts) - min(ts), 'DAY' ) delta
              FROM events
          GROUP BY event_id
       )
     ;
```

Tested on oracle 12c1.

Credits:
Interval formatting taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/970461/)