# Edit the answer that is returned by my select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, intervals

I have a selection to find the difference between two dates

```
select  SUBSTR(to_timestamp('19.09.2019 11:26:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) - to_timestamp('01.01.2019 00:00:00' , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ),8, 12) diff 
from dual
```

The answer I teach is correct

```
261 11:26:00
```

Is it possible to somehow get the answer of this format

```
261 day 11 hour 26 min 00 sec
```

Comment: You need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/970461

Comment: Possible duplicate of [format interval with to\_char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970249/format-interval-with-to-char)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT` and string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM diff ) || ' days'
       || ' ' || LPAD( EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM diff ), 2, '0' ) || ' hours'
       || ' ' || LPAD( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff ), 2, '0' ) || ' minutes'
       || ' ' || LPAD( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM diff ), 2, '0' ) || ' seconds'
         AS diff
FROM   (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-19 11:26:00' - TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
           AS diff 
  FROM   DUAL
)
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | DIFF                                    |
> | :-------------------------------------- |
> | 261 days 11 hours 26 minutes 00 seconds |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=616935b8677ceb515a55f6e18ad33d60)*